# Is that possible to configure Region shortcuts with specific logic in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn

Good time,

I work with a colleague who use #region statements inside Unit-test methods.

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
  #region Arrange
  // Code here
  #endregion

  #region Act
  // Code here
  #endregion

  #region
  // Code here
  #endregion
}
```

Standard outlining keys help me if I want to close such methods, but don't help when I want to expand all Arrange\Act\Assert block inside one method through one key combination. I should go to each region and press Ctrl + M + M. (I know about Expand All, but it has some other problems).

It's annoing, and I want to know if it's possible to expand all regions inside selected or current block. If it's not possible - is there a way to programm it using Roslyn or smth else?

P.S. I use VS 2015.

Upd1. I know about hate regions, but it also blocks regions which are helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CTRL + M + M will collapse/expand the current section.

```
#region test1
    void test()
    {

    }
    #endregion

    #region test2
    void test2()
    {

    }
    #endregion

    #region test3
    void test3()
    {

    }
    #endregion
```

I just selected test1 and test2, at pressing CTRL + M + M it only expanded those two regions.

Comment: It works good, but I have an other situation. I need to expand 3 blocks inside one method. But of cource, it's better than expand block one-by-one.

Comment: Yes but why don't you just select the functions body and use this shortcut? You could try to program a visual studio add-in if this don't matches your whishes.

Comment: you are right! Not this one I've searched, but definitely works! Great thanks.